# bash copy file where some of the filename is not known

Tags: bash

In a bash script i want to copy a file but the file name will change over time. 
The start and end of the file name will however stay the same.

is there a way so i get the file like so:

```
  cp start~end.jar
```

where ~ can be anything?

the cp command would be run a a bash script on a ubuntu machine if this makes and difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A glob (`start*end`) will give you all matching files.

Check out the `Expansion > Pathname Expansion > Pattern Matching` section of the bash manual for more specific control

```
   *      Matches any string, including the null string.
   ?      Matches any single character.
   [...]  Matches any one of the enclosed characters.  A pair of characters separated by a hyphen denotes a range expression; any character that sorts between those two characters, inclusive, using the current locale's collat-
          ing sequence and character set, is matched.  If the first character following the [ is a !  or a ^ then any character not enclosed is matched.  The sorting order of characters in range expressions  is  determined  by
          the  current locale and the value of the LC_COLLATE shell variable, if set.  A - may be matched by including it as the first or last character in the set.  A ] may be matched by including it as the first character in
          the set.
```

and if you enable `extglob`:

```
  ?(pattern-list)
         Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
  *(pattern-list)
         Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
  +(pattern-list)
         Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
  @(pattern-list)
         Matches one of the given patterns
  !(pattern-list)
         Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

Comment: One bit of advice; try to make the pattern as specific as possible, to avoid matching more files than expected. For example, if you knew the middle part was a timestamp in YYYY-MM-DD format, prefer `start-????-??-??-end.jar` to `start*end.jar`. Or even better, `start-@(19|20)[0-9][0-9]-@([1-9]|10|11|12)-@([1-9]|1[1-9]|2[1-9]|3[01]-end.jar`.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `glob` to capture the variable text:

```
cp start*end.jar
```