# regex - find files that don't match

Tags: regex, bash, find

I have a list of directories where most are in a format like `./[foobar]/`. However, some are formatted like `./[foo] bar/`.

I would like to use `find` (or some other utility my shell offers) to find those directories *not* matching the first pattern (i.e. having text outside the square braces). Until now, I was unable to find a way to "inverse" my pattern.

Any ways to do this?

Comment: To clarify - you are looking for a regex that matches a string that has text between `//` characters that is not between `[]` characters? Would that mean any string that doesn't match `/[.*]/` - with appropriate escaping of the `/` and `[]` characters, of course... ?  As for "match something that is not"... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine find with grep and it's -v option. `find . -type d | grep -v "[foobar]"`

Comment: Probably the most simple solution.

Comment: This is incorrect. You need to switch to `grep -Fv` to switch to literal matching, or escape the regex special `\[` because the current regular expression will match any string which contains either `f` or `o` or `b` or `a` or `r` anywhere.

Comment: this is not ideal because does not stop `find` from 'finding' the files that do not match. This is a major setback when you are deal with thousands+ files and directories that you want to exclude.

Answer (score 3):

A simple regular glob will work in this particular example:

```
$ ls
[a]b [ab]
$ echo \[*\]
[ab]
```

For more complex patterns you can enable `extglob`:

```
!(pattern-list)
     Matches anything except one of the given patterns
```

([and similar globs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15252503))

Or using find:

```
find dir ! -name ...
```

Comment: Works in general, but piping `find` to `grep` seems easier.

Comment: As long as you're not going to use it beyond simply looking, that will be fine, though I think the glob is easier (and safer if there are any spaces in file names).

Answer (score 2):

`find` supports negation by means of `!` and `-not`. The latter is not POSIX-compliant. In order to use `!` you have to precede it with backslash or put it inside single quotes.

Answer (score 1):

```
find -type d -name '*\]?*'
```

Unless you insist on opening bracket check...