# How to get files do not match a pattern

Tags: bash, shell

Here is my script

```
data_dir="/home/data"
shopt extglob
files=!($data_dir/*08142014*)
echo ${files[@]}

for file in $files[@]
do 
  #blabla
done
```

/home/data contains multiple files with different date info within file name, thus I should be able to get a list of files that does not contain "08142014".

But kept get syntax error. It seems files is just "!(/home/data/*08202014*)", while I want a list of file names.

Did I miss anything? Thanks

Comment: Not enough information. Is there only one file matching that pattern, or should there be more? Does `ls` show you the same?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15253702/regex-find-files-that-dont-match

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
data_dir="/home/data"
shopt -s extglob
files=($data_dir/!(*08142014*))

for file in "${files[@]}"
do 
  echo "$file"
done
```

- To set `extglob` you need to use `shopt -s extglob`
- To set array your syntax isn't right
- Check how array is correctly iterated

Answer (score 1):

You can use ->

```
files=`ls $data_dir | grep -v 08142014`
```